# Problema con bucle while: no funciona or

Tags: c++

No me funciona el or en este bucle while:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
main ()
{
    char s;
    do{
        cout<<"\n\t\t> Ingrese el sexo: ";
        cin>>s;
    }while (s!='f' || s!='m');
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: QUizás te convenga probar con máximo de paréntesis, para no tener que apostar sobre la precedencia de operadores:  ((s!='f') || (s!='m')). De todos modos, nota que esa expresión siempre da true, porque no se puede ser igual a los dos strings a la vez. Sospecho que quisiste poner while !((s='f') || (s='m'))

Comment: Además, recuerda que si puedes, en C++, acostúmbrate a usar como operadores lógicos `and` y `or` en lugar de `&&` y `||`

Comment: @CarlosUrda `or` es aceptado como operador y palabra clave en `C++` (consulta la sección 2.11.2 Keywords [del estándar](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf)), se presenta como una alternativa a `||`, seguramente para sistemas o codificaciones que carezcan de el caracter `|`.

Comment: @Carlos `and` y `or` son exactamente lo mismo que `&&` y `||`. Sí podríamos discutir que `and` y `or` sean más legibles que `&&` y `||`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No te funciona porque en vez de **||** (OR) debes utilizar **&&** (AND). Usando OR la condición del while siempre será verdadera pues cuando sea 'f' no será 'm' ;-)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
main ()
{
    char s;
    do{
            cout << "\n\t\t> Ingrese el sexo: ";
                cin >> s;
    }while (s!='f' && s!='m');
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ya lo probe amigo, muchisimas gracias! me siento tonto de tropezar en algo tan basico

Comment: @Malthael si la respuesta te ayudó ¡no olvides en marcarla como aceptada!