# Mi do while se ejecuta infinitamente

Tags: c++

Este es es el fragmento que se ejecuta de forma infinita, ayuda porfa.

```
**do {
    cout<<"\n\n¿Desea volver a hacer los cálculos para otro cilindro? 1. Si 2. No";
    std::cin>>d2;
     }
    while ((d2!=2)||(d2!=1));**
```

Comment: ¿ No será `(d2!=2) && (d2!=1)` ?

Comment: Es que && sería el operador para "y" y realmente no necesito que ambas opciones sean true sino cualquiera de las dos por eso use el || que se supone es el "o".

Comment: Pero lo que necesitas es que se repita únicamente cuando el valor de `d2` es diferente a `1` ó `2`. Es decir, `d2` debe ser diferente de `1` "y" de `2`.

Comment: `d2` solo puede tomar un valor a la vez. Por lo tanto, `d2 != 2 || d2 != 1` será siempre verdadero ya que si `d2 == 2`, `d != 1` y si `d2 == 1`, `d2 != 2`.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Problema con bucle while: no funciona or](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/21423/problema-con-bucle-while-no-funciona-or)

Answer (score 4):

El código ha entrado en un bucle infinito porque la condición siempre devuelve true.

Con estos 2 valores y utilizando el operador `||` *(* **OR** *)*, devuelve true si al menos uno de los operandos es true y el `do while` entra en un bucle infinito.

`D2` *no puede ser igual a* `1` y `2` *al mismo tiempo*.
Si `d2` es diferente de `2` O `d2` es diferente de `1`, siempre será `true`.

Esta es la lógica de **OR**:

```
true  || true   = true
true  || false  = true
false || true   = true
false || false  = false
```

El flujo de ejecución del **While**:

```
Hacer:

(Comprobar condición)
    Si la condición es verdadera
        regresa a Hacer
```

Primero ejecuta el código y luego compara si la condición es verdadera; si la condición es verdadera, regresa al `do`.

Pero en tu caso, ambas devuelven `true`. Para corregirlo, en algún momento de la verificación, deberá devolver `false` para detener el bucle.

**Dependiendo** *de lo que trate el operador* `XOR`, *puede resolverlo*

```
// XOR
true ^ true    =  false
true ^ false   =  true
false ^ true   =  true
false ^ false  =  false
```

COD:

```
do {
    cout << "\n\n¿Desea volver a hacer los cálculos para otro cilindro? 1. Si 2. No";
    std::cin >> d2;

    
} while ((d2 != 2) ^ (d2 != 1));
```

De esta forma `do while` continuará si no tecleas 1 o 2 cualquier otro número te devolverá en el mensaje **"** `¿Quieres volver a hacer los cálculos para otro cilindro? 1. Si 2. No` **"**

**(** [*operadores logicos*](https://cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/operators/) **)**

Comment: Graciassssssss.